# Firefox wrongly redirects to the mobile version of site

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-10.10, user-agent

I am continuously being taken to the mobile version of certain sites when using Firefox version 3.6.13 on Ubuntu Maverick. The problem is as such - 
1. This happens only for Firefox while other browsers show the proper site.
2. Happens only to a few sites.

For me the issue was evident on - http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/ . On searching online, found that it happened to others when accessing certain sites like hotmail as well.

It may be that this has something to so with the way these sites are interpreting the standard Firefox URL on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the problem after searching online. The solution was to go to about:config and filter by useragent.
Then make the following changes- 
general.useragent.vendorComment   to lucid from maverick
general.useragent.vendorSub       to 10.04 from 10.10

This is just a temporary workaround I guess.
This is what worked for me. Other people had suggested changing Ubuntu to Firefox.

Also you may need to clear cache, history etc and restart browser.